# Rails 3.1 Migrate to PostgreSQL locally

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I want to use PostgreSQL locally since I have to use it on Heroku.  I have my app already built and all so I need to convert what I have using MySQL now.

I have

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and I already did `brew install pg`.  I ran `rake db:setup` and receive this error

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your `database.yml` file to use the pg adapter?

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: cookbook
    username: uid
    password: pwd
    host: localhost
```

It looks like your database.yml is still configured to use SQLite.

Comment: Oh, how do I do this? Just replace all references of sqlite3 -> pg?

Comment: Do I leave username/password like that?  Or how do I know what to change it to?

Comment: They'll need to be set to whatever you configured your PQSQL accounts to be.  You'll also have to change the database from `cookbook` to whatever your database is named.